# Cardinal of the set of all dense and enumerable subsets of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem statement:
Calculate the cardinal of the set consisting of all the dense and enumerable subsets of $\mathbb R^2$

The attempt at a solution:

I couldn't go farther than this: If $A$ is the set consisting of all the dense and enumerable subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, then $A\subset B \space$, $\space B=\{ S \subset \mathbb R^2: |S|=\aleph_0\}$. So $|A|\leq |B|={(c^2)}^{\aleph_0}=c^{2\aleph_0}=c^{\aleph_0}$

I have no idea what else to do, could anyone give me suggestions or hints on how could I go on?, for example, I could find a lower bound for the cardinal of $A$. Or maybe there is a bijective function from this set to another set $C$, where the cardinality of $C$ is easy to calculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to go one step further:

$$|B|=\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}\;.$$

So $|A|\le\mathfrak{c}$, and you’ll be done if you can find $\mathfrak{c}$ different countable dense subsets of $\Bbb R$. What about sets of the form $\Bbb Q^2\cup\text{(something very simple)}\,$?

Comment: As an aside, it seems pretty clear from context that the OP meant $(c^2)^{\aleph_0}$ rather than $c^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: @Erick: It would have been clear if I’d seen the $^2$. *sigh* My eyes aren’t what they once were.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my notation, I meant just what Erick Wong wrote, I've edited the original post.

Comment: @user100106: No problem. I really would have interpreted it correctly if my eyes hadn’t slipped right over the exponent in $\Bbb R^2$, so I’m at least partly responsible for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Don't worry. Your answer was very useful, I just didn't know that $c^{\aleph_0}=c$, with that information and the other suggestion I can finish it from here. Thanks Brian!

Comment: @user100106: Excellent! You’re welcome.